# Does an unnecessary brocho pesucha on Hallel necessitate a brocho siyuma?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, blessing, mistakes, hallel

We had an interesting question arise in our Shul this past Yom Yerushalayim. Our shul has a minhag of saying Hallel without a brocho in Shacharis. At one of the minyanim, the chazzan said a brocho at the beginning of Hallel ("likro es ha'hallel"), out of habit. The question is, does the fact that he said a brocho at the beginning of hallel *necessitate* the recitation of the final brocho ("melech me'hulal ba'tishbachos") at the end? I don't have any reason to assume either way—I'm not even sure that the two brochos are related—but I'm still curious. Note: the fact that some hold a brocho should be said on Hallel on Yom Yerushalayim should be excluded from this analysis.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in cases where there are different opinions regarding whether the blessings should be recited to begin with?

Comment: ...or is your question also in a case where no one would say to make either bracha _ab initio_?

Comment: @Fred - I'd much rather ignore the latent question as to whether the brocho is required for that Hallel, and focus just on the question of once the brocho was said, whether a closing brocho is needed.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Like you said, I'd rather ignore the current context and understand the general situation. I don't want to get sidetracked in a discussion on whether a brocho should be said for Hallel in X or Y scenario.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19086/what-if-you-forgot-to-wash#comment47175_19086

Comment: Does your question only apply to Hallel, or to other inadvertently started opening blessings? Do you know the Halachah in other cases, and do you have reason to assume it would be different for Hallel?

Comment: @SethJ ..Like the b'rachos of p'sukei d'zimra, leining, or m'gilla, for instance (though each might have idiosyncratic issues).

Comment: @eykanal Whether there are opinions that say to recite a b'racha might be a relevant factor. You don't have to get into a debate about a particular case, but you should stipulate an assumption one way or the other regarding whether there are opinions both ways regarding reciting a b'racha ab initio.

Comment: I concur with @Fred. It may be that, if the Berachah is unnecessary, the Halachah is not to recite the closing Berachah, though what is done in the past (a moment ago, when the opening Berachah was recited out of habit) is done; on the other hand, if one does not recite the Berachah MiSafek, then the Halachah might (emphasis on _might_) be different.

Comment: @SethJ - I'm just asking about Hallel, but to the extent that they're related, I'd be interested in knowing the halacha.

Comment: @Fred - See above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Mishna Maseches Sukkah 3:11 it says that the after Beracha of Hallel is not obligatory like the first Beracha -so it's obvious that one would not say the after Beracha in the case of the question.