# Is the Beracha Aharona independent of the Beracha Rishona?

Tags: halacha, blessing, mistakes, eating

If someone has a Kezayit of cake, for example, and he finishes it without having blessed before eating it, does he make an after-blessing?

Comment: If your breath smells of garlic, would you solve the problem by eating more garlic??[?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19086/what-if-you-forgot-to-wash#comment47175_19086)

Comment: @DoubleAA I think I remember once a Talmid Hacham telling me that you should make a Beracha Aharona.

Comment: @DoubleAA The issue in B'rachos 51a is whether to recite the b'racha rishona after finishing to eat, thus possibly "eating more garlic" with a b'racha l'vatala (at least according to Rashi's reading of the gemara). Accordingly, it sounds like the parallel you're suggesting in the OP might be that he should not make a b'racha acharona as it would somehow be l'vatala. That's not what you meant, is it? Is there a reading that it refers to blessing before eating more, in which case more garlic would refer to not making a b'racha? Or did you mean the more general reference in Shabbos 31b?

Comment: If I have some cake, eat a bit and forget to make a b'racha, but want to go on eating cake, I certainly should make a b'racha rishona now on the remaining cake as I have not yet made a b'racha that covers it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, he makes one. Source: *The Halachos of Brochos*, by Rabbi Yisroel Pinchos Bodner, (self-published, distributed by Feldheim, 1989, second printing, March 1990), chapter 15, section C.2, citing *Magen Avraham* 172:2 and *Mishna B'rura* :3. (The *Machatzis Hashekel* there notes that this is obvious.)