# Must a kazayit be eaten immediately?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shiurim-measurements, bread

In order to recite an after-beracha —- take bread, for example —- must the full kazayit be eaten right after making the opening-beracha, or could one taste the bread and wait a period of time before eating the shiur kazayit (or two) in one sitting?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30873/759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The STAR-K [writes](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/2164/a-halachic-guide-to-seudas-shabbos-and-lechem-mishna/#_ftnref8)

> Although ideally a kezayis should be consumed immediately, it is also
>   acceptable for one to initially eat a small amount of bread after the
>   brocha and then eat a kezayis of bread within a two, or at least four
>   minute span later in the meal.

Comment: Do they explain why there is any preference?

Comment: @DoubleAA They don't seem to offer an explanation for the preference - perhaps it's a concern one won't eat a kezayis within the time frame, but I wouldn't speculate that without knowing poskim mention such a reason

Comment: Then this may only apply on Shabbat and not be a general rule about blessings

Answer (score 0):

[Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bracha_Achrona#Minimum_measures_to_be_obligated_in_Bracha_Achrona) says

> One is only obligated to make a Bracha Achrona on a food if one eats a
>   Kezayit of food in Kedi Achilat Pras.
>
> How long is Kedi Achilat Pras?
>
> Shiurei Torah (Rav Chaim Noeh 3:15 pg 203) writes that Kedi Achilat
>   Pras is 4 minutes.
>
> Vezot HaBracha (pg 6) writes that many poskim (and quotes Rav Elyashiv
>   as one of them) agree. See Aruch HaShulchan 202:8 and Kaf HaChaim
>   210:8.
>
> Rav Ovadyah Yosef (Sh"t Yachave Daat 1:17) rules that Kedi Achilat
>   Pras preferably is 4 minutes and after the fact (Bedieved) it is 7.5
>   minutes.
>
> Or Letzion (vol 2, 14:17) holds that Kedi Achilat Pras preferably is 4
>   minutes and after the fact (Bedieved) it is 6 minutes.

So, ideally you have 4 minutes.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question