# Washing (with a blessing) before continuing a meal with no more bread

Tags: halacha, blessing, netilat-yadayim-washing, meal-seudah

[As noted elsewhere on the site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/19094), [the *Shulchan Aruch* (*OC* 164:2)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&pgnum=116) rules that someone who, in the middle of a bread meal, touches his thigh must then wash his hands and say the blessing "*al n'tilas yadayim*" before continuing to eat.

Does that apply even if he's not going to eat any more bread? (On the one hand, the *SA* doesn't seem to differentiate.<sup>[1]</sup> On the other, we don't normally wash hands and say "*al n'tilas yadayim*" before eating non-bread foods.)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> As [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa) points out in a comment, [*SA OC* 177:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%96#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91) indicates that "we're not accustomed to sever ourselves from bread until" the end of the meal: they always had in mind that they might eat more bread. Thus, the case I ask about, where someone had in mind that he would *not* eat more bread, didn't exist in the time of the *SA*, which may explain why the *SA* didn't differentiate that case from the opposing case.

Comment: Assuming that my logic [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75312/9682) is correct, perhaps that question can answer this one. If washing is independent of eating afterwards, it shouldn't matter whether you want to eat more bread.