# Changed mind about eating after making netilat yadayim:

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, hefsek-interruption

What should one do if one washes, with the intention to make ha'motzi on bread, makes the bracha al netilat yadayim and is then interrupted and is no longer able to eat, and/or no longer wants to eat. Is the bracha al netilat yadayim a bracha levatalah?

Comment: Why would you think it is? Or isn't? Whatever it is you are thinking, please [edit] it in. Include as well any research or evidence you have about this to help others.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52734/759

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%98_%D7%99%D7%92 biur halacha implies this is not a problem

Answer (score 1):

No. The Ritva in Chullin (106b) rules such because at the time that you washed you had in mind to eat. R' Ovadia Yosef (Yabia Omer YD 1:21) also [rules this way](http://halachayomit.co.il/he/ReadHalacha.aspx?halachaid=3612).

[This site](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01881.html#HtmpReportNum0004_L2) also brings down such a Halacha, but I'm not sure what their source is.

Comment: So how who bless on a turmos and the turmos falls need to say BSKMLV

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @kouty In this case one said a blessing on a Mitzva and did the Mitzva. In that case one said a blessing on food but didn't eat the food.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree. This enhance my ununderstanding about the real kind of bracha rishona. In fact theoretically i was possible to place it after the startinf of eating

Comment: @DonielFilreis see tosfot brachot 39a

Comment: @kouty Ah, got it. Yeah, I'm gonna go with DoubleAA on this one.